# General grounds for refusal - False representation

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, spouses

I am applying for a UK Spouse Visa.

There is a question "Have you ever: Given false information when applying for a visa, leave to enter, or leave to remain".

I initially answered "no" because, surely I'd never done that?

But then I realized, I had been scolded by a Border Force Officer.

The first time I flew into the UK with my then-girlfriend (now wife), I was asked about the purpose of my visit, and I never mentioned her or visiting her.

We travelled a month later, and when we reentered the UK, the Officer this time asked if I had a UK partner, and I answered that I did, and we had just arrived together. Now I was taken aside, and waited 15 minutes until I was brought back to the same officer, who gave me 6 months Leave to Enter, but scolded me, informing me that I was to always let them know that I had a UK partner.

Now of course I'm terrified that my visa will be refused, as deception is mandatory grounds for refusal. I wasn't asked the first time if I had a UK partner, but I also didn't mention her as part of my reason for visiting. Obviously I didn't understand that I absolutely needed to have mentioned her. And I was honest when asked directly on my second visit.

Does anyone know if I explain this in my visa, if I'll still be denied? Does it help that I told an Officer the second time, and was granted Leave to Enter, and was informed I needed to always mention her in the future?

From OP: I did initially answer No but then the thought jumped out that I was mistaken. I was asking on this forum, to help me figure out whether to answer Yes or No, what to say, and how the answer would weigh on my application decision.

Comment: Have you submitted the application and have you been through the Bio-metrics process?

Comment: False means deliberate dishonesty, not incorrect. Were you deliberately dishonest?

Comment: why did you remove very important details from your question in the latest edit? That doesn’t help you in anyway.

Comment: I've had my question answered elsewhere, and have been told that because I was let in, then my situation does not rise to the level of needing answer 'Yes'.

Comment: Terrible advice I must say, However It's your life so chose the advice you deem fit.

Comment: I've been advised that had the officer believed I gave false information, which is a significant offense, I wouldn't have been let in with a verbal warning.

Comment: @greatone Regrettably false means incorrect, not just deliberately dishonest.

Comment: If you don't mind doing so, please let us know the outcome of this application. Thanks!

Comment: @DJClayworth https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/837104/false-representation-v1.0ext.pdf

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you did give false information during your landing interview.

If I were you, I would answer Yes to that question on the subsequent applications and explain the episode briefly. Since you were still let in the country, I believe that won't have a considerable effect on the outcome of your visa application.

---

**If you have already submitted the application with a No**:

But now that you have answered that question incorrectly, and you know from your experience that they know about that already, unfortunately there are strong chances of a refusal.

Comment: @UKVisaHopeful: And I would stress that they keep records about your motivations and entries, as you have seen. In the 15 minutes they will probably had time to add that to your records. There are nearly no "wrong answers" (meaning automatic refusal), just some answers could requires further research, and because of the minor problem, I think it would not affect the visa. but if you answer no (and they have the record), they may assume you are a serial liar [not just nervousness]

Comment: OP gave false information yes, but was that "when applying for a visa, leave to enter, or leave to remain" ? I would say not.

Comment: Why not? A landing interview is ‘leave to enter’ stage.

Comment: @HankyPanky ah OK, I thought 'leave to enter' was something that had to be applied for with a formal application, like a visa.

Comment: @HankyPanky Where did the OP give **false** information?  As far as I can see, all they did was not volunteer information.

Comment: @jpatokal The OP was asked about the purpose of the first trip. Flying with the girlfriend suggests that spending time with her was at least a significant purpose. Instead, the OP talked about visiting other people.

Comment: @jpatokal see the edit history of the question. Plus, if there was no false information provided for the first time, there was no need for the scolding the second time.

Comment: Given that the question is at least arguable, it is much, much safer to answer "yes" and say what happened. Answering "no" risks a deception ban, which can apply even if the false statement is not material to the application.